# Can we automatically make a users Drupal account inactive when their membership expires?

Tags: civimember

We are running on Drupal 7.67 and Civi 5.13.4.

Our client wants to be able to block users whose memberships have expired and request them to contact the client to reinstate their membership.

We have been trying to build a custom module to be able to do this and are finding it challenging.

Is there any way that we would be able to use the CiviMember Role Sync or the CiviGroup Role Sync modules to help us achieve this is a simpler manner? If not, how should we proceed.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making the account inactive is probably not the best user experience.  You could use [CiviMember Roles Sync](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/drupal/#civimember-roles-sync), permission your member content appropriately and show your inactive members the renewal page.

Comment: Agree you should be able to do this as described if you make sure that Authorised 'role' in Drupal has effectively no additional permissions to Anon, and make a Member have a 'member role' as Aidan describes. Then a lapsed Member still has an 'account' but it doesn't give them anything extra when they log in other than a link you would provide for them to Renew, Rejoin.

Comment: CiviMember Roles Sync is perfect for this - we use it for many projects even if the org does not sell any memberships as it gives administrators the opportunity to control what logged in users can see/access simply by changing their Membership status (eg at different stages of going through a Volunteer application process);